# How to run a thread in the background in python

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

```js
class CORSRequestHandler (SimpleHTTPRequestHandler):

  def do_GET(self):
    thread1 = threading.Thread(target=test())
    thread1.daemon = True
    thread1.start()
    return SimpleHTTPRequestHandler.do_GET(self)

def test():
    while True:
        print "Hello"
        time.sleep(2)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    BaseHTTPServer.test(CORSRequestHandler, BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer)
```

I need to run a server meanwhile printing Hello in the background. Can you please tell me what i am doing wrong because if a try to enter the url the page never loads up. However Hello is being printed and the server does start.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to pass method `test` in `target` keyword argument of `threading.Thread`, not what `test` returns.
So, replace

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=test())
```

with

```
thread1 = threading.Thread(target=test)
```

When you do `target=test()` test method is called right then, hence the infinite loop and the request never returns.